# Drawing a Custom View and Resizing it to fit the screen size

Tags: java, android

I am creating book reading application with Android Studio and I have some problem.
please see attached image.

1. I inserted image and set fit screen
2. I created Custom view and Draw drawRect.

I have Rectangles X and Y position but it is large.
I want to fit screen for all devices.

Can some one help me please?
thank you.

this is Custom view code

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Rect rectangle;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

    File DBFile = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "Rectangles.db");
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DBFile, null);
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ExportLine WHERE PageNo = 1", null);

    cur.moveToFirst();

    while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {
        int lineX = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("X"));
        int lineY = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("Y"));

        int lineMaxX = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("XMax"));
        int lineMaxY = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("YMax"));

        rectangle = new Rect(lineX , lineY, lineMaxX, lineMaxY);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);

        cur.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

[image: This is i Created]

[image: I want to like this]

First Image i created
I want to like last image

i have all coordinates

Comment: First of all, `file operation and database operation` in onDraw method is very very very worst.

Comment: just i need to how to fix coordinates to like image